Special homogeneous linear ODE of the second order
I found the following question in Earl D. Rainville's textbook Intermediate Course in Differential Equations:
Show that you can always complete by elementary methods the solution of the equation:
$\ y''-xQ(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$
Now, I'm not sure what elementary method could work here. I'm also struggling to get help from Google, since searching "homogeneous linear equation of the second order" just gives a bunch of results with constant coefficients. Any nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

What does it mean to 'complete' the solution?

Is the last term supposed to contain a factor of $y(x)$? Otherwise the equation is (1) in general inhomogeneous and (2) just a first-order linear equation in $y'$, from which $y$ can be computed by antidifferentiating.

I edited the question to include a factor of $y$ in the last term of the ODE, in accordance  with Problem 8, p. 5 of the book.

Hint. One solution to the ODE can be found by inspection: it's $y_1(x)=Cx$. Another solution can be found with the ansatz $y_2(x)=xv(x)$. Indeed, substituting the latter in the ODE, we obtain
$$
xv''+2v'-xQ(x)(xv'+v)+Q(x)xv=0 
$$
$$
\implies xv''+(2-x^2Q(x))v'=0, \tag{1}
$$
which can be reduced to a first order ODE with the substitution $v'=u$:
$$
xu'+(2-x^2Q(x))u=0. \tag{2}
$$
Eq. $(2)$ is separable, so it can be reduced to quadratures.
